# MVC4 Rename and change Location of _ViewStart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I'm making a single page application. Don't want to use _ViewStart.  I like to have my startpage inside the root of my project directory and rename it to index. It seems possible. But how ? Please check out these project before post.

[CodeCamper Project](https://github.com/NicholasMurray/CodeCamper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set these line inside web.config to true.

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```